# Asymptotic expansion of an integral at the blow-up

Tags: integration, analysis

I got an integral

$$
\int ^t _0 (t-s)^{-\alpha} (T-s)^{-\alpha} ds
$$

for some constants $t<T$ and I want to investigate the asymptotic behavior of the integral as $t \uparrow T$. In particular, I am looking for the asymptotic expansion in terms of $T-t$, i.e. something like

$$
\int ^t _0 (t-s)^{-\alpha} (T-s)^{-\alpha} ds = \sum _{k=0}^N c_k(T-t)^{a_k} + O(T-t)^\beta
$$

for some constants $c_k, a_k$ and $\beta$.

**My attempt:**

I presume the integral should have the leading order term of order $(T-t)^{1-2\alpha}$ since if we replace $t$ with $T$ in the integrand, we get

$$
\int ^t_0(T-s)^{-2\alpha}ds = \left.\frac{(T-s)^{1-2\alpha}}{-2\alpha + 1}\right|^t_0 = \frac{(T-t)^{1-2\alpha}}{1 - 2\alpha} - \frac{T^{1-2\alpha}}{1 - 2\alpha}
$$

Another idea would be to use Parseval formula for Fourier or Mellin transform.

Comment: Show that
$$I \sim \int_0^T (T - s)^{-\alpha} (T - s)^{-\alpha} ds$$
for $\alpha < 1/2$ and
$$I \sim \int_{-\infty}^t (t - s)^{-\alpha} (T - s)^{-\alpha} ds =
(T - t)^{1 - 2 \alpha}
 \int_0^\infty u^{-\alpha} (1 + u)^{-\alpha} du$$
for $1/2 < \alpha < 1$.

$I$ has a closed form in terms of the hypergeometric function ${_2 F_1}$, so the above corresponds to the two leading terms in the expansion of ${_2 F_1}$. $\alpha = 1/2$ is the logarithmic case.

Comment: Can I expand $I$ in terms of the hypergeometric function for $z=T-t$? (obvious substitution $s = tu$ would yield hypergeometric function in terms of $\frac tT$)

Comment: If you mean a closed form, there are connection formulas between $F(z), F(1 - z), F(1/z)$, where $F$ is a hypergeometric function. So we can express $I$ in terms of $F((T - t)/T)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.